# Sorting table in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table, alphabetical-sort

I am absolutely new in lua and just want to modify an existing script.

There is a function that writes values in a list. I would like to sort them by name:

```
function display_moments()
  local counter = 1
  if(moments[media_name]~=nill) then
    moments_list = main_layout:add_list(1,4,4,1) -- empty moments_list widget to prevent duplicate entries
    for i,j in pairs(moments[media_name]) do
      moments_list:add_value(i,counter)
      counter = counter + 1
    end
  end
end
```

Do I have the chance to get my list sorted in any way?

Answer (score 0):

From Lua [table.sort (ref manual)](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) if your list is as follows

```
local _list = {1,4,4,1}
print(unpack(_list)) -- 1, 4, 4, 1
table.sort(_list)
print(unpack(_list)) -- 1, 1, 4, 4
```

you can add following line after the loop, given that your list is an array

```
table.sort(moments_list)
```